# How to access files from one S3 bucket into another bucket without making them public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, cors, bucket

To make files accessible to other S3 buckets, we either need to make the bucket public or enable cors configuration.

I have an HTML page in one public bucket which is hosted as a static website. In another bucket, I have mp3 files. This bucket is not public. From the first bucket, the HTML invokes a script.js file that tries to access the MP3 files in the second bucket using the resource URL. This is not directly possible and gives a 403 error. Hence, I wrote a CORS configuration for bucket-2 with the ARN of the first bucket in . Still, the script was unable to access the MP3 files. I also tried using the static website URL instead of ARN. Again got a 403 error. Is it possible to enable the script.js to access the mp3 files in bucket-2 without making bucket-2 public?

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand that your javascript is run in the customer's browser window, hence this is the browser trying to access the mp3 file in your second bucket, not the first bucket.

Knowing that, there is no easy solution to solve your problem, beside opening access to the second bucket and using CORS as you tried (but CORS alone will not give access to the private bucket)

**Proposal 1 : manually generated signatures**

If you just want to give access to a couple of files in the second bucket (and not all files) I would recommend to include in your javascript a fully signed URL to the object in the second bucket.  Signed URLs allow to access individual objects in a non public bucket, as per [S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html).  However generating signatures is not trivial and requires a bit of code.

I wrote this command line utility to help you to generate a signature for a given object in a private bucket.
https://github.com/sebsto/s3sign

The AWS command line has also a `presign` option nowadays
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html

Also, signature are time-bounded and the maximum age is [7 days](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/bucket-policy-s3-sigv4-conditions.html) So if you choose this approach, you will need to re-generate your links every week.  This is not very scalable but can be easy to automate.

**Proposal 2 : dynamic signature generation on the web server**

If you decide to move away from client-side Javascript and use server side generated pages instead (using Python, Ruby, PhP etc ... and a server) you can dynamically generate signatures from your server.  The downside of this approach is that you will need a server.

**Proposal 3 : dynamic signature generation, serverless**

If you're familiar with AWS Lambda and API Gateway, you can create a serverless service that will dynamically return a signed URL to your MP3 file.  Your static HTML page (or client side Javascript) will call the API Gateway URL, the API Gateway will call Lambda and Lambda, based on the path or query string, will return the appropriate signed URL for your MP3.

Proposal 2 and 3 have AWS costs associated to it (either to run an EC2 server, or for the API Gateway and Lambda execution time), so be sure to check [AWS Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/pricing/) before choosing an option. (hint : Proposal 3 will be more cost effective)

The real question is WHY do you want to create this ?  Why can't you have all your public content in the same bucket using fine grained S3 access policies when required.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to AWS. I was trying to build an application using S3, Lambda, API Gateway. The MP3 files are dynamically generated by a lambda function and the script tries to access them based on their ID. So fine-grained access is not possible. I just wanted to know if it is possible to make them available without making the bucket public. But you have a point- if it is passed on to the client, it is public anyway and hence there is no harm in making the bucket public. Thank you for a detailed explanation. :)